# How to troubleshoot unresponsive ASP .NET Web API on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, deadlock, health-monitoring

I am having an issue with Web API hosted on IIS. Here are the details

- Environment: ASP.Net MVC, IIS, SQL server
- Web API hosted on separate server, Load balanced with 2 servers, Big
  IP

The API works fine in PROD but in lower environments it becomes unresponsive or very slow. Sometimes it takes 5 minutes to process a request. Otherwise it takes forever. The issues occurs only once or twice a month. App Pool recycle or IIS restart didn’t seem to help. But after rebooting server it works fine and processes the same request in 10 – 20 seconds.

Authentication is set for every request (i.e. 401 followed by 200). When issue occurs the IIS log has only 401 entry. Issue seems to happen on only 1 server as it starts to work fine after restarting only that server.
During the issue when another API request comes, it gets to the affected server. What might be the reason that the request doesn’t go to another server which is free?

The system logs were fine. The CPU utilization was 3%, Memory usage etc. looks good on the server at the time of issue. IIS configuration settings are same as PROD and look good.

What tools can be used to monitor IIS Apps, Server? Are there any free tools? Any help to troubleshoot this issue will be great.

Some errors on server:

Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: This app can't be activated by the Built-in Administrator. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

The Open Procedure for service "BITS" in DLL "C:\Windows\System32\bitsperf.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.

Windows cannot load the extensible counter DLL ASP.NET_2.0.50727. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the Windows error code.

Cryptographic Services failed while processing the OnIdentity() call in the System Writer Object.

**UPDATE:**
DebugDiag2 Analysis - CrashHangAnalysis report.
Is this causing deadlock?

```
Thread ID   Total CPU Time  Entry Point for Thread
2   00:00:00.031    ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
0   00:00:00.030    w3wp+2e50
1   00:00:00.000    nativerd!DllGetClassObject+24680
3   00:00:00.000    ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
4   00:00:00.000    w3tp!THREAD_POOL::CreateThreadPool+350


4 Threads (40% of all threads) have this same call stack.
Note: Grouping of identical threads can be disabled in the 'Preferences' tab of the Analysis Options
Thread 2 - System ID 4704
Entry point   ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
Create time   9/20/2021 1:00:34 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.031


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Thread 3 - System ID 2576
Entry point   ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
Create time   9/20/2021 1:00:34 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.000


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Thread 8 - System ID 2112
Entry point   ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
Create time   9/20/2021 1:00:34 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.000


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Thread 9 - System ID 5832
Entry point   ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
Create time   9/20/2021 1:01:04 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.000


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Instruction Address       Source
[0x7ffadb029444]    ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+14    
[0x7ffadaf9eb4e]    ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+296e     
[0x7ffada7184d4]    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+14   
[0x7ffadafd1781]    ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21
```

Comment: You can find quite a few typical ASP.NET issues and how to analyze them https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex/

Comment: Are there any related error messages in the event viewer and console? There are some tools that can analyze the performance of iis, the network, etc., you can use Google to search by yourself.

Comment: @samwu : I have updated the error details

Comment: I can only suggest the divide and conquer method. Remove authorisation and see if that is the issue. Make the API return a static value (instead of whatever internal processing it's doing) and see if that helps. You just have to break the API process up into seperate pieces and isolate which piece is the issue

Comment: If the 401 is being returned but not the 200, it suggests the problem is the authentication process that takes place after the client receives the 401. What kind of authentication does your system use? Does it access an external system (e.g. database) of some kind?

Comment: @JohnWu Yes it accesses external systems  SQL DB. Every request is authenticated 401 followed by 200. It works fine immediately after restarting the server.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If not, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.